# You are trying to add a non-nullable field to category without a default

Tags: python, django

Возникла ошибка с миграциями в базе данных в django:

```
You are trying to add a non-nullable field 'url' to category without a default; we can't do that (the database needs something to populate existing rows).
Please select a fix:
 1) Provide a one-off default now (will be set on all existing rows with a null value for this column)
 2) Quit, and let me add a default in models.py
Select an option: fix
Please select a valid option:
```

Comment: Какое слово в тексте непонятно?

Answer (score 1):

Так ясно же говорит, что пытаешься добавить не нулевое поле без значения. Это бывает если у тебя уже есть записи в таблице, а пытаешься добавить новый столбец. Джанго не понимает чем заполнить этот столбец, а нул не разрешен.
Либо ставь для url null=True, blank=True, либо ставить что-то как дефолт значение.